# Came/come/coming from (background)

Tags: american-english

I’m specifically asking in the context of describing background here.

Are these all grammatically correct (especially #3)?

1. I come from nothing
2. I came from nothing
3. I am coming from nothing

If so, do they mean any different from each other?

How about these below?

1. I come from an accounting background
2. I came from an accounting background
3. I am coming from an accounting background

I hear #1 and #3 used most frequently in this context. Are they also all grammatically correct? If so, again, how do they mean any different from each other?

Comment: Where have you heard someone say "I am coming from nothing"?

Comment: @alphabet I think they meant they've heard #3 in the second group. While I don't think it's very common, it seems more idiomatic than #3 from the first group.

Comment: I think all 3 forms mean approximately the same thing. The past tense variant suggests that  the background was further in the past, like before you started your current job, while "I come from" would be used shortly after this has changed.

Comment: @Barmar I don't doubt that they've heard it, but I'm wondering *where* they heard it. It could've been from a non-native speaker, for instance.

Comment: @alphabet Quite likely. Present progressive is a common mistake of certain foreign speakers, like Russians.